# Saved Gdiplus::Bitmap always has Alpha Channel (RGBA/ARGB)

Tags: c++, bitmap, png, gdi+, pixelformat

I have a Gdiplus::Bitmap (in C++) in PixelFormat32bppARGB format and convert it to PixelFormat32bppRGB by using:

```
        Gdiplus::Bitmap* bitmapRGB = new Gdiplus::Bitmap(bitmap->GetWidth(), bitmap->GetHeight(), PixelFormat32bppRGB);
        Gdiplus::Graphics graphics(bitmapRGB);
        graphics.DrawImage(bitmap, Gdiplus::Point(0, 0));
```

If I check the format of the RGB-Bitmap it is correct (RGB):

```
bitmapRGB ->GetPixelFormat() == PixelFormat32bppRGB
```

If I save the Bitmap and check its format (i.e. with Gimp) there is a fourth channel.

```
    CLSID pngClsid;
    GetEncoderClsid(L"image/png", &pngClsid);
    bitmapRGB ->Save(path, &pngClsid, NULL);
```

How do I achieve to get a png with a RGB-Pixelformat?

Comment: "I have a Gdiplus::Bitmap (in C)" This is not possible. This is no valid C code. C does not have `::` or `new` operator. C++ does but it a completely different language. Please take a few seconds to pick the correct tags.

Comment: Why do people keep saying "C++ is a completely different language"? IMHO this obscures the fact, that you can program "C in C++" style, getting the benefits of better type checking (and finding bugs C does silently accept). So a "completely different language" would not allow that. (You cannot restrict what you use in a LISP program and hope a C compiler compiles it because LISP is a completely different language). I programmed "C" in C++ for many projects and reaped the benefits, including being able to "fall back" to a C compiler when an embedded system only has that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PixelFormat32bppRGB` is still 32-bit. `PixelFormat24bppRGB` is needed for 24-bit format:

```
Gdiplus::Bitmap* bitmapRGB = new Gdiplus::Bitmap(
    bitmap->GetWidth(), bitmap->GetHeight(), PixelFormat24bppRGB);
```

The `new` operator is not necessary, use one of the appropriate constructor to make sure there is no memory leak:

```
//convert:
Gdiplus::Bitmap bitmap(L"source.jpg");
Gdiplus::Bitmap bitmapRGB(bitmap.GetWidth(), bitmap.GetHeight(), PixelFormat24bppRGB);

Gdiplus::Graphics graphics(&bitmapRGB);
graphics.DrawImage(&bitmap, Gdiplus::Point(0, 0));

CLSID pngClsid;
GetEncoderClsid(L"image/png", &pngClsid);
bitmapRGB.Save(L"destination.png", &pngClsid);
```